Closed form for this generalisation of the gamma function. $f(x+1)=f(x)g(x+1) $
Just for curiosity I want to generalise the Pi function i.e $f(x+1) = f(x)g(x+1)$ for some differentiable function, I know this function probably has no closed form for general functions $g$ as I couldn't find any but maybe it exist and  more experienced user can find it.

For a differentiable function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and $\exists M \in \mathbb{R}$ st $\forall x>M$ $g(x)\ge0$ with $g(1)\ne 0$ define $f(x+1) = f(x)g(x+1)$

To make it clear that $f$ depends on $x$ and $g$ I will write it as $\Pi(x, g(t))$, $\Pi(x, t)$ is just the ordinary pi function.
.
I found analogous result to the Gauss product by a non rigorous approach.
$$\Pi(x, g(t)) = \lim_{n \to \infty } g(n)^x \prod\limits_{1\le k\le n} \frac{g(k)}{g(k+x)} $$
With this It is easy to see that  $\Pi(x, t^a) =\Pi(x, t)^a  $, $\Pi(x, e^t)=1 $.
As I said before, probably  there is not a closed form for a general function $g$ put if a closed form could be found when $g$ is any polynomial satisfying the conditions of $g$   this could be extended to power series which cover a wide range of functions.

You should be able to find a pattern for polynomial $g(x)$ here. Also your product formula seems correct

There is a meaningful formula if, for some natural number $n$,
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\ln(g(x)) = 0.
$$
Under this condition, the solution is
$$
f(x) = f(0) \lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\prod_{i = 1}^N \frac{g(i)}{g(x + i)}\right)\prod_{i=1}^n \exp\left(\binom xi \Delta^{i - 1}(\ln \circ\ g)(N + 1)\right).
$$

Derivation
Let $F = \ln(f)$ and let $G = \ln(g)$. We will use $\Delta^n$ to represent the $n$th forward difference operator. That is, for any function $f$,
\begin{align}
\Delta^0f(x) &= f(x),\\
\Delta^{n+1}f(x) &= \Delta^{n}f(x + 1) - \Delta^{n}f(x).
\end{align}
Note that, since $F(x + 1) = F(x) + G(x + 1)$, we have
$$
\Delta^1F(x) = G(x + 1), \quad \text{and in general} \quad \Delta^nF(x) = \Delta^{n - 1}G(x + 1).
$$
Also, since $\lim_{x \to \infty}G^{(n)}(x) \to 0$, it follows that
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \Delta^kG(x) = 0, \quad k \geq n.
$$
We will use Newton's series, which can be thought of as a discrete version of Taylor series:

Consider a function $f$. Given nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$ with $a \leq b$,
$$
f(x + a) = \sum_{i = 0}^b \binom ai \Delta^if(x).
$$

(This is typically expressed with an infinite sum, but the binomial coefficients will be $0$ for all but the first $a$ terms.)
This means that, if $x$ is a natural number, we can let $b = \max(x, n)$, and then
$$
F(N + x) = \sum_{i = 0}^b \binom xi \Delta^iF(N)
$$
for any $N$. But also if $N$ is a natural number, we know that
$$
F(x + N) = F(x) + \sum_{i = 1}^N G(x + i).
$$
Combining these two facts, we have
\begin{align}
F(x) &= F(x + N) - \sum_{i = 1}^N G(x + i)\\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^b \binom xi \Delta^iF(N) - \sum_{i = 1}^N G(x + i)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^b \binom xi \Delta^iF(N) + F(N) - \sum_{i = 1}^N G(x + i)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^b \binom xi \Delta^iF(N) + F(0) + \sum_{i = 1}^N G(i) - \sum_{i = 1}^N G(x + i)\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^b \binom xi \Delta^iF(N) + F(0) + \sum_{i = 1}^N (G(i) - G(x + i))\\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^b \binom xi \Delta^{i-1}G(N+1) + F(0) + \sum_{i = 1}^N (G(i) - G(x + i))\\
&= F(0) + \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{i = 1}^N (G(i) - G(x + i)) + \sum_{i = 1}^b \binom xi \Delta^{i-1}G(N + 1)\right).
\end{align}
But remember that $\lim_{N \to \infty} \Delta^kG(N + 1) = 0$ for $k \geq n$. So we can drop the $b$ to just $n$, and we're left with
$$
F(x) = F(0) + \lim_{N \to \infty} \left(\sum_{i = 1}^N (G(i) - G(x + i)) + \sum_{i = 1}^n \binom xi \Delta^{i-1}G(N+1)\right).
$$
This no longer relies on $x$ being an integer, so all we have to do is exponentiate to arrive at the true solution:
$$
f(x) = f(0) \lim_{N \to \infty}\left(\prod_{i = 1}^N \frac{g(i)}{g(x + i)}\right)\prod_{i=1}^n \exp\left(\binom xi \Delta^{i - 1}(\ln \circ\ g)(N + 1)\right).
$$

Notes

This formula is "meaningful" in that it is the unique solution whose logarithm's $(n + 1)$st derivative approaches $0$ as $x \to \infty$.
This is natural because we started with the assumption that the $n$th derivative of $\ln(g)$ approaches $0$. In that sense, $\ln(g)$ behaves like a degree $(n-1)$ polynomial for large $x$. We would then expect its sum, which equals $\ln(f)$, to behave like a degree $n$ polynomial in the same sense. This is the solution for which that holds.

This is indeed an extension of @pie's formula in the question. Take $n = 1$ to arrive at theirs.

Though $n$ only needs to be big enough for $(\ln \circ\ g)^{(n)}(x)$ to approach $0$, the rate of convergence can (usually) be greatly improved by using higher values of $n$ than are strictly necessary.

This formula is not guaranteed to converge for non-integers unless we further restrict $g$. In particular, if $G^{(n)}$ oscillates (for instance, $G(x) = \sin^2(\pi x)/x$ with $n = 0$), then it may not work. However, it will always converge if $G^{(n)}(x)$ is monotonic for large $x$.

This is essentially an implementation of the method described in this paper: How to Add a Noninteger Number of Terms: From Axioms to New Identities



One can plug in $x=0,1,\dots$ and find a pattern. Also, call $f(0)=c$:
$$f(x+1)=g(x+1)f(x)\\x=0:f(1)=g(1)f(0)=c\,g(1)\\x=1:f(2)=g(2)f(1)=c\,g(1)g(2)\\x=2:f(3)=g(3)f(2)=c\,g(3)g(2)g(1)\\\vdots$$
One notices, after substituting $x+1\to x$, that
$$f(x+1)=g(x)f(x)\implies f(x)= c\prod_{n=1}^{x-1}g(n) $$
Now one needs a continuation for $x\notin\Bbb N$. However, there is a continuation if $g(x)=a\prod_\limits{j=1}^k(x-r_j)$, a factored polynomial, then:
$$f(x)=c\prod_{n=1}^{x-1}\left(a\prod_\limits{j=1}^k(n-r_j)\right)=ca^{x-1}\prod_{j=1}^k\prod_{n=1}^{x-1}(n-r_j)=ca^{x-1}\prod_{j=1}^k(1-r_j)_{x-1}$$
We used the Pochhammer symbol which is extended to real numbers via $(a)_n=\frac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(a)}$. Using a finite series for $g(x)$ would be more complicated.
